# Java replace smileys in string

Tags: java

I have the following function to replace smileys in a `String`:

```
public String replaceSmileys(String text) {
    for (Entry < String, String > smiley: smileys.entrySet())
        text = text.replaceAll(smiley.getKey(), smiley.getValue());
    return text;
}

static HashMap < String, String > smileys = new HashMap < String, String > ();
smileys.put("&:\\)", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/1.png'/>");
smileys.put("&:\\D", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/2.png'/>");
smileys.put("&;\\)", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/3.png'/>");


String sml = replaceSmileys(msg);
```

Im getting this error:
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {} near index 4
&:\P`

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Added that now i get error: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 3
&;\\)`

Comment: Sorry, wrong problem. Your problem is actually that (for example) `D` doesn't need to be escaped - you only need `&:D`, not `&:\\D`. Same with `&:\\P` (which I assume is in some code you haven't posted here).

Comment: New error :) `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 1
&;)`

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Mac  \D is valid.  Just that it will match any non-digit character.

Comment: @Mario: I agree, it's a valid regex. It's not what the OP wants though, based on the context. And `\P` (see the example exception) certainly isn't valid.

Comment: @Mac  From where is the OP getting '&:\P'?  Is he/she correcting the code as responses appear?

Comment: @Mario: that's how the question was originally posted. Either the OP didn't provide all of the source, or made a typo in the exception.

Comment: @Mac  Thanks.  We must definitely have some ESP if we were able to answer the question :-) at his/her satisfaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only your parentheses need to be escaped, not your literal characters. So:

```
smileys.put("&:\\)", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/1.png'/>");
smileys.put("&:D", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/2.png'/>");
smileys.put("&;\\)", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/3.png'/>");
```

Note change on second line.

Basically, if you don't escape the close-parentheses, the parser gets confused because it thinks it has missed an open-parenthesis. So you **must** escape the parentheses. On the other hand, plain-old letters (D in your example) don't require escaping, since they don't form a part of a regex construct.

Answer (score 1):

The code segment should work perfectly except that if the second pattern intends to match a smiley and not an `&` followed by a `:` and then a non-digit character, then it should be.

```
    smileys.put("&:D", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/2.png'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sml = replaceSmileys("&:)");
        System.out.println(sml);
    }

    static String replaceSmileys(String text) {
        HashMap < String, String > smileys = new HashMap < String, String > ();
        smileys.put("&:\\)", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/1.png'/>");
        smileys.put("&:D", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/2.png'/>");
        smileys.put("&;\\)", "<img src='http://url.com/assets/3.png'/>");
        for (Entry < String, String > smiley: smileys.entrySet())
            text = text.replaceAll(smiley.getKey(), smiley.getValue());
        return text;
    }
}
```

Output -

```
<img src='http://url.com/assets/1.png'/>
```

Comment: i have edited the code.. i forgotten to add & in function call